# Web access to android application - price and category

Tags: android

I am trying to collect information about Android apps.  I am trying to build my program and I need to have a web access to price and category of android applications.  Any idea about the API, how I can access the information?

Comment: You are willing to do something like http://www.cyrket.com/ ?

Comment: Can't have access to cyrket.com, for some reason I see blank page, 
I want to read the android apps -both price and category, I see few websites that already have the information, not sure how they read it, API to Android appstore will help, Thanks Shosho

Answer (score 0):

Each market has its own policies regarding "web access to price and category of android applications". The Android Market does not make this information available.

Comment: Are you sure? How do you think few websites have this info?

Comment: @Shosho: yes, I am quite sure

Comment: I am not familiar with cyrket.com

Comment: Surprised to hear that. cyrket has been down for months. But there are other sites which seem to have access to the android market data, for e.g. androlib.com, androidstats.com. I can see comments from the market on androlib.com (although they are not always up-to-date). Wonder how they do it.

Comment: They just reverse engineered the way that the Android Market works. This information is not publicly available.

Comment: cryket used to "spam" the markets feed so to stop websites like this google implemented a system in the market to prevent this clients that spammed to grab information in real time.

Sites like androlib cache their data and are not in real time (update every 24 hours?) therefore they are able to dodge googles spam block.

Comment: Thanks for all responses, I should be more clear about the question, 
I am looking to have the access to the apps in android app-store from Android app-
From my Android application to have access to Price and Category of other application on Android app-store.

Any idea if Android supports the API for that?

Thank, ShoSho

Comment: "Any idea if Android supports the API for that?" No, it does not.